# Min-max normalization of a column in postgresql doesn't work when trying to update the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query for min,max normalization of a column and it works fine:

```
SELECT
    1.00*(number_of_pedestrians_killed-Min_number_of_pedestrians_killed)/number_of_pedestrians_killed_Range
FROM
    (
    SELECT
       number_of_pedestrians_killed,
       MIN(number_of_pedestrians_killed) OVER () AS Min_number_of_pedestrians_killed,
       MAX(number_of_pedestrians_killed) OVER () - MIN(number_of_pedestrians_killed) OVER () AS number_of_pedestrians_killed_Range

    FROM
       ways
    ) x ;
```

but when I try to add these values into a table column it does not work

```
UPDATE ways
SET ways.Number_of_pedestrians_killed_normalized = 1.00 * (ways.Number_of_pedestrians_killed - Min_number_of_pedestrians_killed) / number_of_pedestrians_killed_Range
FROM
  (
      SELECT number_of_pedestrians_killed,
        min(number_of_pedestrians_killed) OVER () AS Min_number_of_pedestrians_killed,
        max(number_of_pedestrians_killed) OVER () - min(number_of_pedestrians_killed) OVER () AS number_of_pedestrians_killed_Range

    FROM ways
  ) x ;
```

the ERROR is: column "ways" of relation "ways" does not exist.
I tried doing it without ways. but I get again an ERROR saying that the column reference "number_of_pedestrians_killed" is ambiguous. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the syntax you need to do this:

```
UPDATE ways w
    SET Number_of_pedestrians_killed_normalized = 1.00 * (w.Number_of_pedestrians_killed - x.Min_number_of_pedestrians_killed) / x.number_of_pedestrians_killed_Range
FROM
    (
        SELECT number_of_pedestrians_killed,
               min(number_of_pedestrians_killed) OVER () AS Min_number_of_pedestrians_killed,
               max(number_of_pedestrians_killed) OVER () - min(number_of_pedestrians_killed) OVER () AS number_of_pedestrians_killed_Range

        FROM ways
    ) x ;
```

But be ware, there is no `where` clause !  With that it means you will update each row of the table multiple time (the number of result from the select).

You'd better do something like:

```
update ways w
    set ...
    from ( select id, ... from ways group by id) x
    where w.id=x.id;
```

Comment: your solution run but it is taking too long to compute, while the select statement doesn't take more than 5-7 secs. (I have 199793 rows)

Comment: I added a comment on multiple update. Be ware about the `where` clause.

Comment: I don't get it, both columns are in one table why do I need the where clause? And it would be w.gid I guess

Comment: Without the `where` it is like you do "for each result on select xxxx then update ways set value_normalized= previous_result"  It means you update the table a lot, and at the end, you will have only 1 single value for all your lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
UPDATE ways
    SET Number_of_pedestrians_killed_normalized = 1.00 * (ways.Number_of_pedestrians_killed - x.Min_number_of_pedestrians_killed) / x.number_of_pedestrians_killed_Range
FROM (SELECT min(number_of_pedestrians_killed) as Min_number_of_pedestrians_killed,
             (max(number_of_pedestrians_killed) - 
              min(number_of_pedestrians_killed)
             ) AS number_of_pedestrians_killed_Range
      FROM ways
     ) x ;
```

This aggregates the values in the subquery and then uses them for the update.